# If I use WordPress REST API V2 and someone makes an app using it. Will my site count the posts views from the APP? And if not, then how?

Tags: rest-api, json

I'm making a mobile app on both `Android` and `iOS` and I can fetch the posts and even open them but I don't know if `WordPress` will count the new views from my `App`

Will `WordPress` do that automatically? If not, then how can I do such a thing?

I'm a beginner so please, be kind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**WordPress does not count views or traffic,** it's not a part of WordPress' feature set. Plugins and code snippets can add this but it's highly specific to the service you're using.

Usually for apps you will need to integrate tracking into the app itself. But how you would do that is specific to the **service** you choose, not WordPress.

To answer this you will need to consult the documentation for the service you've chosen to integrate. *There isn't a WordPress based answer.*

Comment: Can you recommend some plugins that serve this purpose? And by ``plugins`` you mean WordPress plugins right?

Comment: I cannot recommend any plugins, what you need to choose is a service not a plugin. A plugin on its own can't track views reliably without an external service or external software. WordPress doesn't track views and any solution that claims it can do that in just a plugin is going to have major reliability issues. E.g. there's a plugin that stores view counts in post meta, and it's extremely unreliable with a major performance cost. If you want to host it yourself you will need dedicated software on the server, not a WP plugin/extension

Comment: Fundamentally, this isn't a WP problem, and it doesn't have a WP solution. There are lots of traffic analytics options out there, and 1 really big one that's everywhere, they just require a JS snippet in the footer of your site. Eitherway, WP doesn't track views, that's the answer to your question. If this doesn't answer your Q please clarify it further, otherwise consider marking it as accepted using the tick under the voting controls